# How to get all value from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have..

```
var genre = ["M","F"];
```

without single quotes and need

```
["M", "F"]
```

Not

```
M,F
```

With quotes and [ ]; Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? You want the string or array ?

Comment: you're doing it right wats the problem?

Comment: Try this parsing javascript [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry, I get the value with jquery. So, I have:
var genre = ["M","F"];

And need, ["M", "F"], all the value, like a string.

Comment: So you have a string (`var genre = '["M", "F"]'`) and you need to convert it into an actual JavaScript array object (`var genreArray = ["M", "F"]`). Is that right?

Comment: No, I have ( ["M","F"] ), without single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
var genre = ["M", "F"];
alert(JSON.stringify(genre));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function strToArr( str ) {
    var arr = [];
    if( typeof str === 'string' ) {
        str = str.substring( 1, str.length - 1 );
        arr = str.split( ',' );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how many will like it, but try

```
var genre = '["M","F"]';
genre = eval(genre )
```

If you don't like to use eval() then use @YuanZhaohao's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094429/how-to-get-all-value-from-an-array-in-javascript/18094556#answer-18094531)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, this will do it:

```
var str = '["a","b","c"]';

var arr = str.split(/\"]|\["|\","/g).slice(1,-1);
```

You end up with an array like `["a", "b", "c"]`

**Note:** you might want to do extra checks in case of the possibility of unexpected format like (e.g. with some random spaces `'["a", "b" ,"c"]'`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string, try this:

```
genre = genre.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + '' + b; });
```